# How to create an adjacency matrix of a directed graph?

Tags: python, dictionary, matrix, adjacency-matrix

I am trying to make an adjacency matrix of a directed graph in python.
I understand the concept of adjacency matrix, but I am not able to create an adjacency matrix in python.
I have represented the directed graph using inlinks and outlinks where "inlinks" are incoming edges to a node and "outlinks" are outgoing edges from a node:

```
data = {'19.json': {'outlink': [], 'inlink': []}, 
        '26.json': {'outlink': [], 'inlink': []}, 
        '4.json': {'outlink': [], 'inlink': []}, 
        '25.json': {'outlink': [], 'inlink': []}, 
        '1.json': {'outlink': [], 'inlink': ['17.json', '2.json']}, 
        '24.json': {'outlink': [], 'inlink': []}, 
        '13.json': {'outlink': [], 'inlink': []}, 
        '16.json': {'outlink': [], 'inlink': []}, 
        '14.json': {'outlink': ['17.json', '2.json'], 'inlink': []}, 
        '17.json': {'outlink': ['1.json', '23.json'], 'inlink': ['14.json']}, 
        '15.json': {'outlink': [], 'inlink': []}, 
        '3.json': {'outlink': [], 'inlink': []}, 
        '9.json': {'outlink': [], 'inlink': []}}
```

How can I create its adjacency matrix using the representation above in python?

I am really stuck here.

Comment: If you understand the concept of adjacency matrix, which part of it can you not translate to Python?

Comment: What have you tried to do?  Is that dictionary what you are supposed to convert into your matrix?

Comment: I want to convert it in a matrix format.I don’t know how can I convert it into matrix format

Answer (score 0):

This can be done easily using NetworkX, once you parse your dictionary so to make it more usable for graph creation (for example, a list of nodes connected by edges).

I would go for generating the list of `nodes` and `edges` of your directed graph with

```
# nodes are the keys of the dict
nodes = data.keys()

# edges can be found via list comprehensions to create a list of pairs connected by an edge
outedges = [(k, j) for k in data.keys() for j in data[k]['outlink']] 
inedges = [(j, k) for k in data.keys() for j in data[k]['inlink']]
edges = set(outedges + inedges)
```

and then, pass them to the NetworkX methods for directed graph creation

```
import networkx as nx

# we can create the directed graph
G = nx.DiGraph()

# add all nodes and edges to it
G.add_nodes_from(nodes)
G.add_edges_from(edges)

# we may even draw the graph to inspect it
nx.draw(G, with_labels=True)
```

finally, you can compute the adjacency matrix with

```
M = nx.adjacency_matrix(G).todense()
```